# Python implementation of the mergeSort algorithm

Tags: python, mergesort

I came across the following implementation of the mergeSort algorithm:

```
def merge_sort(x):
    merge_sort2(x,0,len(x)-1)


def merge_sort2(x,first,last):
    if first < last:
        middle = (first + last) // 2
        merge_sort2(x,first,middle)
        merge_sort2(x,middle+1,last)
        merge(x,first,middle,last)


def merge(x,first,middle,last):
    L = x[first:middle+1]
    R = x[middle+1:last+1]
    L.append(999999999)
    R.append(999999999)
    i=j=0
    for k in range(first,last+1):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            x[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            x[k] = R[j]
            j += 1


x = [17, 87, 6, 22, 41, 3, 13, 54]
x_sorted = merge_sort(x)
print(x)
```

I get most of it. However, what I don't understand are the following four lines of the merge function:

```
 L = x[first:middle+1]
    R = x[middle+1:last+1]
    L.append(999999999)
    R.append(999999999)
```

First of all: why does the slicing end with *middle+1* ? Slicing an array in Python includes the last element, right? So, shouldn't it be sufficient to slice from first:middle ? So, what is the *+1* there for? 
Secondly: Why do I have to append the huge number to the lists? Why doesn't it work without? It doesn't, I checked that. But I just don't know why.

Comment: *Slicing an array in Python includes the last element, right?* – No: `'asdf'[:2] → 'as'`; `'asdf'[2] → 'd'`.

Comment: Maybe this [algo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-merge-sort/) is clearer

Comment: I guess the huge number is supposed to be "larger than any other number" which of course is not really true generally.

Comment: I can help you at least with one of your problems... The big number in the end is for the algorithm to know that the end of one of the sides has been reached. This means that after that just the elements from the other side get inserted into x. In order to keep the algorithm as simple as possible these big numbers get inserted. Also note that you need one comparison less now because you have don't need to check if the end of the list has been reached

Comment: @Cedced_Bro: What about the for loop with index k ? Shouldn't this ensure I only iterate through the loop as often as I need to? Also: The big number actually is part of both L and R. So a comparison such as R[i] <= L[i] can still result in True, for this entry.

Comment: @Luk no the index is for ensuring that you only copy the elements of the x array and so don't copy the helping bounds. If you think about it: the copy process will be executed for the elements from first to last (included) so you never copy bounds but just the elements from x. Now these big numbers just prevent you from getting out of the bounds of L and R

Comment: That implementation is so crude, that I'd strongly advise against trying to understand it...
Here's a good explanation of MergeSort in python:
https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: *Slicing an array in Python includes the last element, right?*

No, Like range function Python slicing doesn't include the last element.

```
> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
> a[1:4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Q2: Regarding the below snippet.

```
 L = x[first:middle+1]
    R = x[middle+1:last+1]
    L.append(999999999)
    R.append(999999999)
```

Without appending those large numbers to the lists, your merge code could have been different something like below.

```
   # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            x[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            x[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
    # Checking if any element was left 
    while i < len(L): 
        x[k] = L[i] 
        i+=1
        k+=1
    while j < len(R): 
        x[k] = R[j] 
        j+=1
        k+=1
```

As @Cedced_Bro pointed out in the comment section, those largest numbers are used to know that the end of one of the sides has been reached. 
If you observe the above code snippet, if we run out of numbers in one list we ideally get out of the for loop and inserts the remaining elements of other lists in the temp array if any.

Appending those large numbers is an intelligent way to avoid those two for loops. But it has some cost of unnecessary comparison of 999999999 with remaining elements in the other list.

Comment: aha, ok. Thx very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the spaghetti-style nested function, simply recur would do, from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Python

```
from heapq import merge

def merge_sort(m):
    if len(m) <= 1:
        return m

    middle = len(m) // 2
    left = m[:middle]
    right = m[middle:]

    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right)
    return list(merge(left, right))
```

The indexing shouldn't have +1 since Python slices don't overlap if they are the same index, i.e.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> middle = 4
>>> x[:middle]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[middle:]
[5, 6]
```

Moreover the `heapq` implementation of merge would have been more optimal than what you can write =)