# Python: Understanding recursion on the example of sorting an array

Tags: python, recursion

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372242/python-implementation-of-the-mergesort-algorithm/59373100#59373100) question, I have given the python code for a mergeSort algorithm. Hereby, the `merge_sort2()` function is a recursive function.

Now, I am trying to understand the callflow of this function:
Say we are given a list with 8 entries, such as

`[17, 87, 6, 22, 41, 3, 13, 54]`

It will be split like this:

```
  [17, 87, 6, 22]          [41, 3, 13, 54]

[17, 87]   [6, 22]       [41, 3]   [13, 54]

[17] [87] [6] [22]       [41] [3] [13] [54]
```

So. I think, internally, sth like this will happen:

```
middle = (0 + 7) // 2             # = 3
merge_sort2(x, 0, 3)
    middle = (0 + 3) // 2         # = 1
    merge_sort2(x, 0, 1)
        middle = (0 + 1) // 2     # = 0
        merge_sort2(x, 0, 0)      #does nothing
        merge_sort2(x, 1, 1)      #does nothing
        merge(x, 0, 0, 1)
    merge_sort2(x, 2, 3)
        middle = (2 + 3) // 2     # = 2
        merge_sort2(x, 2, 2)      #does nothing
        merge_sort2(x, 3, 3)      #does nothing
        merge(x, 2, 2, 3)
    merge(x, 0, 1, 3)
merge_sort2(x, 4, 7) 
    ...
merge(x, 0, 4, 7)
```

yeah. Somewhat like this. I guess I am having troubles understanding recursion. But does this look right?

Comment: I think that looks good. In my experience, it is helpful to resist the temptation of unrolling. Instead, trust in the recursion and work on how to build the result up from the result of the recursive calls.

Comment: you're probably right. Thx!